# Using a class vs just functions

Tags: python-3.x, theory

I am going to be creating a script that parses through an XML (very large, .5gb+), and am trying to think of how to efficiently do it.

Normally, I would do this in AutoIt, as that's my 'normal' language to use for things, but I think it's more appropriate to do it in Python (plus I'd like to learn more python).

Normally how I'd do this, is create a constant with all the 'columns' I'd need from the XML, use that to match and parse it through into an array (actually 2 arrays, cause of subrecords), then pass sets of the array(s) to the system of record as JSON objects/strings.

In Python, I'm not sure that's the best route.  I was thinking about making a class of the object, then creating instances for each record/row of the XML that I'd convert to JSON and then submit.  If I feel ambitious, I'd even work on getting it to be multithreaded. My best option would be to pull out a record, then submit it in the background while I work on the next record, up to say, 5 to 10 records, but perhaps that's not good.

My question is, does it seem like I'm using a class just to use a class, or does it seem like a good reason to do it?  I admit my thinking is colored by the fact that I haven't used classes much (at all) before, and am using it because it's neat and new.

Is there actually a totally better way that I'm overlooking because I'm blinded by new/shiny concepts, or lack of knowledge of the program (this is probably likely to me)?

I'm hoping for answers that will guide me in a general direction - this is part of my learning the language and doing the research myself really helps me understand what I'm doing and why.  Unfortunately, I think I need a guide here on this point.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bit broad and opinion based question, without knowing more specifics. If it can be done with or without classes then there’s no clear cut answer and you can go either way. Maybe try both since you’re learning?

Answer (score 3):

This debate is largely situational in nature, and will depend on what you intend to do within your program. The main thing I would consider is, *Do I need to encapsulate properties (data) **and** functionality(methods/functions) into a single grouping?*

Some additional things that come to mind, in terms of pros vs. cons of using a class (object) in this context:

**Reasons to use a class:**

1. If potential future maintainability would warrant 'swapping' in a new class into an existing structure within the program.
2. If there are attributes that would hold true for all instances of the class.
3. If it makes logical sense to have a group of functions separated out from the rest of your program.
4. More concise options for ensuring immutability
5. Providing a type for the underlying fields meshes well with the rest of your program.

**Reasons not to use a class:**

1. The code can be maintained purely through the addition of new functions.
2. You aren't performing functional tasks on the fields stored (*e.g. storing `create_date`, but needing only to work with `age` - this can lend itself better to an object that doesn't expose `create_date`, but rather just a function `get_age`*).
3. You have severe performance optimization standards to meet and can't justify calls to functions to ensure encapsulation, any additional memory overhead, etc...

Generally, Python lends itself to using classes since it is an object-oriented language. However, compared to more heavily oop languages like C++ and Java, you can "get away" with a lot more in Python without using classes. If you want to explore using a class, I certainly think it would be a good exercise in use of the language.

**Edit:**
Based on follow-up comment, I wanted to provide an example of using named arguments to instantiate a class with optional fields. The general overview, is that Python interprets the ordering of arguments when considering which argument to assign to internal functionality. As an example:

```
def get_info(name, birthday, favorite_color):
   age = current_time - birthday
   return [name, age, favorite_color]
```

In this example, Python interprets the input arguments based on the order they appear when the method is called:

```
get_info('James', '03-05-1998', 'blue')
```

However, Python also allows for named arguments, which specify the parameter-internal field assignment explicitly:

```
get_info(name='James', birthday='03-05-1998', favorite_color='blue')
```

While at first glance this syntax appears to be more verbose, it actually allows for great flexibility, in that ordering of named arguments doesn't matter, and you can set defaults for arguments that aren't passed into the method's signature:

```
def get_info(name, birthday, favorite_color=None):
       age = current_time - birthday
       return [name, age, favorite_color]

get_info(name='James', birthday='03-05-1998')
```

Below I've provided a more in-depth working example of how named arguments could help the situation you've outlined in your comment (Many fields, not all of them required) Play around with constructing this object in various ways to see how the non-named parameters are required, but the named parameters are optional and will default to the values specified in the `__init__()` method:

```
class Car(object):
    """ Initializes a new Car object. Requires a color, make, model, horsepower, price, and condition.
    Optional parameters include: wheel_size, moon_roof, premium_sound, interior_color, and interior_material."""
    def __init__(self, color, make, model, horsepower, price, condition, wheel_size=16, moon_roof=None, premium_sound=None, interior_color='black', interior_material='cloth'):
        self.color = color
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.horsepower = horsepower
        self.price = price
        self.condition = condition
        self.wheel_size = wheel_size
        self.moon_roof = moon_roof
        self.premium_sound = premium_sound
        self.interior_color = interior_color
        self.interior_material = interior_material

    # Prints attributes of the Car class and their associated values in no specific order.
    def print_car(self):
        fields = []
        for key, value in self.__dict__.iteritems():
            fields.append(key + ': ')
            fields.append(str(value))
            fields.append('\n')
        print ''.join(fields)

# Executes the main program body
def main():
    stock_car = Car('Red', 'Honda', 'NSX', 290, 89000.00, 'New')
    stock_car.print_car()
    custom_car = Car('Black', 'Mitsubishi', 'Lancer Evolution', 280, 45000.00, 'New', 17, "Tinted Moonroof", "Bose", "Black/Red", "Suede/Leather")
    custom_car.print_car()

# Calls main() as the entry point for this program.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Wow, this is a great answer.  I want to try using a class, but my problem that I've run into with it so far is that I would have 60 'attributes' to the class.  And not all of them have values, so I can't really find a good way to intialize the object with putting in 60 values?

Comment: @DW So my gut instinct here was to think about this like Java, where I would use a fluent interface, or the builder design pattern to deal with many fields, only some of which need to be initialized at construction. However, Python supports named parameters which should allow you to only pass the parameters you care about at construction. Essentially create all 60 fields in a single class, but only initialize the ones you need when you actually call the class. I will update my answer with an example when I get a chance!

Comment: inheritance is really overrated - it's mainly a restricted case of composition/delegation - so I would definitely not mention it as the first driving force for using or not using OO (as far as I'm concerned I would actually not even mention it at all). The first and main driving force here is whether you have a need for a set of function to work on a shared set of data.

Comment: @DW if you have 60 candidate attributes then you probably don't have the proper design.

Comment: @JohnStark marking all attributes as protected and providing getters for no good reason is considered totally unpythonic - you can always turn them into computed attributes later on if the needs arises. Also, you may want to learn about string formatting operations - concatenating strings this way is unreadable, error-prone and inefficient.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've updated the code example to remove attribute protection and provided a different method for printing the contents of the class. In this context however(providing example code for the author to explore - who has stated they are new to Python), I don't think the original code was 'unreadable' or error-prone, and didn't need to be optimized for efficiency. The goal was to provide code that the author could run, in order to learn about named parameters; not provide production-level code optimized to print a bunch of strings...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I don't understand your comment about 60 attributes indicating improper design. The author stated they are attempting to parse raw XML into an object. They may not be authoring the XML data, and thus are forced to consume it in whatever manner makes sense because they can't control what is exposed to them. Arguing that 60 attributes is improper design is arbitrary and unhelpful. Why not 100, or 10, or that they shouldn't consume the XML at all?

Comment: @JohnStark first please note that I said "you __probably__ don't have the proper design" - which is a bit different. This being said, that many attributes   most often indicates a "God class" (too many responsabilities) that would benefit from being refactored into smallest, more focused objects. "Parsing raw XML into object" is nothing new, and a typical DOM object as way fewer attributes. In this case I understand that the OP doesn't want a full blown DOM but a simplified domain-specific representation of a "record/row", but it doesn't necessarily  mean he needs a one to one mapping.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Okay, that's fair, I can see where you're coming from. That you shouldn't need a unique field for everything you're parsing; that you could store a hierarchy of data under a single field?

Comment: @JohnStark that's one of the options, indeed

Comment: Unfortunately, this data is indeed coming from an outside source.  It's actually two tables placed into one from a db, and the xml output is the only access.  So in order to work with it, I need to parse it out and put it into two different csv's.  That's why I was thinking maybe they'd be classes.  Since the second table has multiple objects connected to the first one, I could make a predefined set of containers for them to go into (since I'll need to place them into the correct columns in a csv later).